# pass values from view page to controller page in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, html, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to insert the data to the database by php CodeIgniter and display the result in the same page during submit the button. Below is my code.The problem is i do not get any values from view page and i check the print_r which results an empty array. Please help. View Page

```
<div class="container col-lg-4">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('Welcome/gallery1'); ?>                         
<div class="form-group has-info">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
<br>
<label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="inputSuccess">Offer title
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" name="offered" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['offered'])) echo $_POST['offered'];  ?>" id="offered">
<label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="inputSuccess">Offer Description
</label>
<textarea id="description" name="description" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description'];  ?>" class="form-control col-lg-6"  rows="3" >
</textarea>
<br/>
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-4">
<span>SUBMIT
</span>
</button>  
</div> 
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Controller Page

```
public function gallery1()
{                    
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('Login_set'); 
$form_data = $this->input->post();
$data1 = array('offer_id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
'hotel_id'=>1,
'offers_name'=>$this->input->post('offered'),
'offers_description'=>$this->input->post('description')
);
print_r($data1);
$this->Login_set->add_offer($data1);    
$page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
$data['h']=$this->Login_set->select(); 
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_galery.php',$data); 
}
```

Model Page

```
<?php
class Login_set extends CI_Model {
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
}
public function add_offer($data1)
{
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper('url');
if($this->db->insert('offer_hotel1',$data1))
return true;
else
return false;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hold any value in the HTML inputs. simply do:

```
<div class="container col-lg-4">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('Welcome/gallery1'); ?>
<div class="form-group has-info">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <br>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="inputSuccess">Offer title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" name="offered" id="offered">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="inputSuccess">Offer Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control col-lg-6"  rows="3" ></textarea>
    <br/>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-4">
    <span>SUBMIT</span>
    </button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

```
public function gallery1()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('Login_set');
    $data1 = array(
        'offer_id'          =>$this->input->post('id'),
        'hotel_id'          =>1,
        'offers_name'       =>$this->input->post('offered'),
        'offers_description'=>$this->input->post('description')
    );
    print_r($data1);
    $this->Login_set->add_offer($data1);
    $page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['h']=$this->Login_set->select();
    $this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_galery.php',$data);
}
```

The values will be dumped in the Controller as `$this->input->post('description'); $this->input->post('offered');`

and if you want to see if a value is already set in this input, you need to fetch data from database and not do `value="<?php if(isset($_POST['offered'])) echo $_POST['offered'];  ?>"`

Comment: but i donot insert the value to the database

Comment: You are doing $this->db->insert('offer_hotel1',$data1), what do you mean not inserting? what are you trying to do then

Comment: that code doesnot working when i submit the button then values also insert to the database is takes place